# Laravel DB::select is breaking a future transaction

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the following code :

```
DB::select($sql, $params);

DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    return [
        'code' => 500,
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'There was a problem saving your transaction.'
    ];
}
```

Which is causing the following error:

```
message:    "There is no active transaction"
exception   "PDOException"
```

There should be more instructions in the try statement but to show that none of them have an affect they have been removed. It seems to be that select is for some reason opening a transaction and not closing it. (The select is running an SP that returns two result sets but I only want one hence the use of select.) Everything works well without the select statement, and the select statement on it's own doesn't cause any errors and returns what I need. However, if I put the select statement in the try statement it causes an exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work?

```
DB::beginTransaction();

DB::select($sql, $params);

try {
    // your code that could fail
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    DB::rollback();

    return [
        'code' => 500,
        'error' => true,
        'message' => 'There was a problem saving your transaction.'
    ];
} 

DB::commit();

return [
    'code' => 200,
    'error' => false,
    'message' => 'Successful transaction.'
];
```

Comment: This works, however, the select and transaction are in two different functions (the transaction being dependent on the select) so the select ,without needing to move lots of code, needs to be before the transaction. If I do use the above and then open another transaction I get the same error.